# Angular 7 token is undefined after login

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, token

Trying to get the Token value and keep the user login until user click on signout. If I try to save it in variable it shows undefined, where I can see the token value through `console.log()`

**Auth.service.ts

```
signIn(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(response =>
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
          (user) => {
            if(user){
              user.getIdToken().then(
                data => this.token = data
              )
            }
          }
        )
      )
      .then(
        response => {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        }
      )
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
getToken() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
      if(user){
        user.getIdToken().then(
          function(data){
          // console.log(data);
        })
      }
    });
  }
```

**Framework: Angular7**

Comment: which variable are you referring to?

Comment: data => this.token = data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `then` you need to **return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)**. Like this

```
getToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        user.getIdToken().then(function(data) {
          resolve(data);
        }).catch(reject);
      } else {
        reject('Error while executing onAuthStateChanged');
      }
    });
  });
}
```